# Why is Mail.app using so much CPU with gmail and Exchange?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, exchange, cpu

My Mail.app is configured for Gmail and Exchange. For some time now the program has been running out of control. It's pretty much constantly burning 100% of CPU (but only 100%). It's got an astonishing number of threads going (sometimes more than 20). I ran `lsof` (below, somewhat edited) and it seems that it's got an inordinate number of files open. It just makes no sense.

I've checked forums and have seen a lot of people complaining about Mail causing battery life problems, especially with gmail, but that's all limited to initial sync, not to continued use. And it seems mostly restricted to iPhone users.

I've also seen problems with mds, [as have other users][1]. But they haven't gotten answers either.

Help!

```
$ lsof -p 39627
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD     TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  cwd      DIR               14,5      1360        2 /
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   8955936 34247566 /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    678672 35511210 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      5323 33923057 /usr/lib/mecab/dic/apple/ja/LE/unk.dic
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5  16402768 34233234 /usr/share/icu/icudt46l.dat
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      3144 33884370 /System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     65776 33872145 /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libLatinSuppConverter.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    262496 33923053 /usr/lib/mecab/dic/apple/ja/LE/char.bin
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     43752 34152547 /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     32768   666364 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-shm
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52544 33939543 /usr/lib/sasl2/apop.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   9370228 34215471 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   5425538 33891418 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    277424 33939545 /usr/lib/sasl2/dhx.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    116448 33939547 /usr/lib/sasl2/digestmd5WebDAV.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52976 33939519 /usr/lib/sasl2/libanonymous.2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     61264 33939521 /usr/lib/sasl2/libcrammd5.2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    112688 33939523 /usr/lib/sasl2/libdigestmd5.2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     84288 33939536 /usr/lib/sasl2/libgssapiv2.2.0.18.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52864 33939532 /usr/lib/sasl2/login.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     83168 33939527 /usr/lib/sasl2/libntlm.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    124096 33939528 /usr/lib/sasl2/libotp.2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52800 33939530 /usr/lib/sasl2/libplain.2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     75200 33939549 /usr/lib/sasl2/libpps.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     66480 33939551 /usr/lib/sasl2/mschapv2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    516928 34257268 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     62864 33939553 /usr/lib/sasl2/shadow_auxprop.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52864 33939555 /usr/lib/sasl2/smb_nt.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     66016 33939557 /usr/lib/sasl2/smb_ntlmv2.so
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    105872 34205841 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libcldcpuengine.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     77600 33873593 /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      9200 34268628 /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/close.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      8952 34268647 /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoom.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      2856  1418671 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/com.apple.opencl/com.apple.ocl.64.maps
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      8500 34268631 /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fullscreen-normal.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   4765184 34215460 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ArtFile.bin
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     56752 34256800 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreFSCache.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    172032  1418672 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/com.apple.opencl/com.apple.ocl.64.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   1480496 34205813 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   1464064 34205817 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_rgba.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    510336 34217327 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Actions.datadetectors/Contents/MacOS/Actions
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      8398 34217333 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DDBluePopDownButton.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     51084 52427959 /private/var/folders/r0/b2nx7_tx2xl82yhf06c6f4600000gp/C/mds/mdsDirectory.db
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     32768 34496747 /private/var/db/mds/messages/se_SecurityMessages
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   4809320 35718311 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     20460   413910 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Keychains/1Password.keychain
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     22328 22522829 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AIR/ELS/com.nyt.timesreader.78C54164786ADE80CB31E1C5D95607D0938C987A.1/PrivateEncryptedDatak
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     24528 26606093 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     26472 27483906 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Keychains/Microsoft_Entity_Certificates
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     96656 34175129 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/AddressBook.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/AddressBook
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     39040 34204899 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookmarkDAV.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SafariDAVNotifier.framework/Versions/A/SafariDAVNotifier
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     68928 29705336 /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    412424 34302468 /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    171696 34217381 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/com.apple.datadetectorscore.cache.urlifier.system
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   5151552 33904483 /usr/share/langid/langid.inv
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   8660356 34217374 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/com.apple.datadetectorscore.cache.full.system
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    164240 55748900 /private/var/db/crls/crlcache.db
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   2315840 34256805 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    218704 34247585 /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/PlugIns/MailWebPlugIn.webplugin/Contents/MacOS/MailWebPlugIn
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    262704 33872141 /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      7050 34217334 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DDHighlightCornerBL.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      7048 34217335 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DDHighlightCornerBR.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      7052 34217337 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DDHighlightCornerTL.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5      7048 34217338 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/Resources/DDHighlightCornerTR.tiff
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    398144 34253685 /System/Library/Frameworks/Message.framework/Versions/B/Resources/Syncer.syncschema/Contents/MacOS/Syncer
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     78176 34239750 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/AOL.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/AOL
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    136224 34239765 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/Exchange.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/Exchange
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     90656 34239780 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/Google.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/Google
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    121344 34206388 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/iCal.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/iCal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     84672 34296601 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/iChat.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/iChat
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    323504 34206830 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/iCloud.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/iCloud
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    971728 34172838 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSUI.framework/Versions/A/AOSUI
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    349632 34172557 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSAccounts.framework/Versions/A/AOSAccounts
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    720224 34303223 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Versions/A/Ubiquity
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    352352 34210926 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    113712 34253701 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/Mail.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     89184 34239798 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/MobileMe.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/MobileMe
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     94768 34239814 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/OSXServer.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/OSXServer
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     78464 34239825 /System/Library/InternetAccounts/Yahoo.iaplugin/Contents/MacOS/Yahoo
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    314024   666367 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/LSMMap2
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   1718416 34281972 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ServerFoundation
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    237776 33870461 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlatformHardwareManagement.framework/Versions/A/PlatformHardwareManagement
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    564192 34213871 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     77552 34292427 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/YahooSync.framework/Versions/A/YahooSync
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     55480 33924141 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhoneNumbers.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Default.phoneformat
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    126648 33891989 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/tokruleLE.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    219510 33890087 /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/Latn1.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5     52904 33890088 /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/Latn2.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   5018101 33959897 /usr/share/germantok/german.index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    144580 33891473 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HIToolbox.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   1480496 34205811 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_argb.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    490410 33891410 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/Localized.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   2493232 34253539 /usr/lib/libmecab.1.0.0.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   3631376 34267688 /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCMaps.A.dylib
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5  12096866 33923056 /usr/lib/mecab/dic/apple/ja/LE/sys.dic
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5   1794048 34496345 /private/var/folders/r0/b2nx7_tx2xl82yhf06c6f4600000gp/C/com.apple.LaunchServices-034502.csstore
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5  20097804 33923055 /usr/lib/mecab/dic/apple/ja/LE/matrix.bin
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5    599280 34293599 /usr/lib/dyld
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  txt      REG               14,5 297717760 34319272 /private/var/run/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    0r     CHR                3,2       0t0      308 /dev/null
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    1     PIPE 0xffffff8012613e70     16384          ->0xffffff80158262e0
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    2     PIPE 0xffffff8012613e70     16384          ->0xffffff80158262e0
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    3u  KQUEUE                                       count=1, state=0x2
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    4u     REG               14,5 209227776   666363 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    5u    unix 0xffffff802840b3f0       0t0          ->0xffffff8015843578
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    6r     REG               14,5   5425538 33891418 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    7u     REG               14,5 209227776   666363 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    8u     REG               14,5   2826352   666365 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-wal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx    9u     REG               14,5   2826352   666365 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-wal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   10u     REG               14,5     32768   666364 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-shm
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   11r     DIR               14,5       680   666358 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   12u     REG               14,5 209227776   666363 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   13u     REG               14,5   2826352   666365 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-wal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   14r     DIR               14,5       680   666358 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   15u     REG               14,5    184320   670276 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/PubSub/Database/Database.sqlite3
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   16u     REG               14,5      2856  1418671 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/com.apple.opencl/com.apple.ocl.64.maps
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   17u     REG               14,5    172032  1418672 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/com.apple.opencl/com.apple.ocl.64.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   18u     REG               14,5 209227776   666363 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   19u     REG               14,5   2826352   666365 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-wal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   20r     DIR               14,5       680   666358 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   21u   systm                          0t0          
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   22r     CHR               11,0   0t28725      584 /dev/random
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   23u    unix 0xffffff8013be4198       0t0          ->0xffffff802840bee0
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   24u     REG               14,5  28737536 34396561 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   25r     DIR               14,5       136    10703 /Volumes
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   26r     REG               14,5   5151552 33904483 /usr/share/langid/langid.inv
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   27r     REG               14,5   5018101 33959897 /usr/share/germantok/german.index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   28u    unix 0xffffff802840bee0       0t0          ->0xffffff8013be4198
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   29u     REG               14,5    704512   389739 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/MailRecents-v4.abcdmr
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   30r     CHR               11,0   0t13166      584 /dev/random
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   31r  PSXSHM                         4096          FNetwork.defaultStorageSession
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   32u     REG               14,5  18034688  1418762 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/Cache.db
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   33u     REG               14,5  18034688  1418762 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/Cache.db
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   34u     REG               14,5         0 34496926 /private/var/folders/r0/b2nx7_tx2xl82yhf06c6f4600000gp/T/com.apple.AddressBook.ABProcessSharedLock.com.apple.AddressBook.Exchange.70FE45.syncState.lock
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   35u     REG               14,5         0 34496927 /private/var/folders/r0/b2nx7_tx2xl82yhf06c6f4600000gp/T/com.apple.AddressBook.ABProcessSharedLock.com.apple.AddressBook.Exchange.70FE45.operationProcessing.lock
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   36u     REG               14,5    303104 26589901 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/70FE4581-A2DD-4649-9797-7ECDDFF0D672/AddressBook-v22.abcddb
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   37u     REG               14,5   3028992   389728 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   38u     REG               14,5 209227776   666363 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   39u  KQUEUE                                       count=0, state=0
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   40u    IPv4 0xffffff801abe9de0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52636->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   41u    IPv4 0xffffff80272d8fa0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52639->172.20.24.130:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   42u    IPv4 0xffffff801d1736c0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52637->iy-in-f109.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   43r     DIR               14,5       204    48947 /Users
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   44u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad2b500       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52648->17.158.28.53:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   45u    IPv4 0xffffff8024f8c6c0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61410->74.205.58.110:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   47u    IPv4 0xffffff8026949c00       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52644->17.158.28.53:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   48r     REG               14,5    126648 33891989 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/tokruleLE.data
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   49w     REG               14,5    599683 20268401 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Logs/Sync/syncservices.log
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   50u    IPv4 0xffffff801d0b3c00       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52650->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   51u     REG               14,5   3028992   389728 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   52u    IPv4 0xffffff801d0b16c0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62225->smtp.abc.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   53u    IPv4 0xffffff801c1586c0       0t0      TCP 10.71.0.189:56324->pb-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   54u     REG               14,5    303104 26589901 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/70FE4581-A2DD-4649-9797-7ECDDFF0D672/AddressBook-v22.abcddb
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   55u    IPv4 0xffffff801d104320       0t0      TCP 10.71.0.189:56307->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   56u     REG               14,5     61440 26589896 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/70FE4581-A2DD-4649-9797-7ECDDFF0D672/ExchangeSync
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   57u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad3ea40       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52688->172.20.24.130:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   58u    IPv4 0xffffff8024f5b500       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62800->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   59u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e976c0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52675->208.70.137.56:http (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   60u    IPv4 0xffffff801cdc9c00       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52676->208.70.137.56:http (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   61u    IPv4 0xffffff801d10bde0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52678->208.70.137.56:http (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   62u    IPv4 0xffffff80188b54e0       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52677->208.70.137.56:http (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   63u    IPv4 0xffffff801738cc00       0t0      TCP 172.20.213.38:52686->172.20.24.130:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   64u    IPv4 0xffffff801738da40       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61800->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   65u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e97de0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62246->iy-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   66u    IPv4 0xffffff801d174c20       0t0      TCP 10.71.0.189:56371->pb-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   67u    IPv4 0xffffff801c824c20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62230->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   68u    IPv4 0xffffff801cc9f320       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62876->smtp.abc.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   69u    IPv4 0xffffff8025026a40       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61422->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   70u    IPv4 0xffffff801f32d320       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61971->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   71u    IPv4 0xffffff8025010500       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61835->mail.junky.com:imaps (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   72u    IPv4 0xffffff802502d6c0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61973->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   73u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad65320       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62249->iy-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   74u     REG               14,5     40960 26777531 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/70FE4581-A2DD-4649-9797-7ECDDFF0D672/MailRecents-v4.abcdmr
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   75u     REG               14,5   2826352   666365 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope Index-wal
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   76r     DIR               14,5       680   666358 /Users/vy32xxx/Library/Mail/V2/MailData
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   77u    IPv4 0xffffff8024fddfa0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61972->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   78u    IPv4 0xffffff802500c4e0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61622->webmail.abc.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   79u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad3f160       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61858->yx-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   80u    IPv4 0xffffff80188b7160       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61974->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   81r     REG               14,5    144580 33891473 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HIToolbox.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   82r     REG               14,5    490410 33891410 /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/Localized.rsrc
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   83u    IPv4 0xffffff8025028de0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61977->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   84u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e65160       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62238->mail.junky.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   85u    IPv4 0xffffff801d0b0880       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62239->smtp.abc.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   86u    IPv4 0xffffff801d10cc20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62240->iy-in-f108.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   87u    IPv4 0xffffff801c1a76c0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61975->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   88u    IPv4 0xffffff801c17d4e0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61391->205.251.215.170:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   89u    IPv4 0xffffff80272f7de0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61991->webmail.abc.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   90u    IPv4 0xffffff8024fe04e0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61392->server-216-137-35-85.sea4.cloudfront.net:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   91u    IPv4 0xffffff80188b5c00       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61978->webmail.abc.com:https (CLOSED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   92u    IPv4 0xffffff801d107500       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61925->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   93u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e65fa0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61926->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   94u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad48a40       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61927->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   95u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e82fa0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61407->a72-247-139-153.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   96u    IPv4 0xffffff801c1b2c20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61928->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   97u    IPv4 0xffffff8024e90320       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61406->a72-247-139-153.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   98u    IPv4 0xffffff8024fb2c20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61405->a72-247-139-153.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx   99u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad0ac00       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61929->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  100u    IPv4 0xffffff802500efa0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61930->206.190.79.227:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  101u    IPv4 0xffffff801cddcc20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61931->click.virt.exacttarget.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  102u    IPv4 0xffffff8024fb1de0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61375->184.173.175.193-static.reverse.softlayer.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  103u    IPv4 0xffffff801ad68c20       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:62069->smtp.abc.com:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  104u    IPv4 0xffffff80169a5320       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61984->webmail.abc.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Mail    39627 vy32xxx  105u    IPv4 0xffffff801c18dfa0       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.220:61989->webmail.abc.com:h
```